# Tables with several children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have some tables: TvShow, Episodes, and Games.

```
TvShow - has_many Episodes, has_many Games
Episodes - belongs_to TvShow, has_many Games
Games - belongs_to TvShow, belongs_to Episodes.
```

The Games table has fields for tv_show_id and episode_id. Episode ID can be blank, as some games are associated with the show and not a specific episode. I have no problem listing each TV shows episode, and any games associated with that episode.

```
<% @tvshows.each do |tv| %>
<div class="gamebox">
<h3><%= tv.title -%></h3>
    <% tv.episodes.each do |episode| -%>
    <%= episode.title %><br />
    <ul>
        <% episode.tv_show_games.each do |g| %>
        <li><%= g.title %> (<%= g.user.name %>)</li>
        <% end %>
    </ul> 
        <% end -%>
</div>
<% end -%>
```

However, I'd also like to be able to grab only those Games that have no episode association. What is the best way to go about doing this? I realize I'd likely have to create a method that only queries Games with empty episode_id fields, but other than that, I'm somewhat stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

rails 3

```
@game = Game.where(:episode_id => nil)
```

rails 2

```
@game= Game.find_all_by_episode_id(nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL where clause

```
@games = Game.where('episode_id IS NULL')
```

or a Rails 2 selector

```
@games = Game.where(:episode_id => nil)
```

or a Rails 3 selector

```
@games = Game.where(episode_id: nil)
```